# Can't create a new project in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I need help with Ionic4.
I am trying to create a new project but I am getting this error:

> npm i npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer
>   maintained, try this instead: npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc npm WARN
>   deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other
>   alternatives. npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is
>   in maintenance only, flatted is its successor. npm ERR! Unexpected end
>   of JSON input while parsing near '...v/7+T+UmfF7FFAzvKrLbt'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-18T15_07_32_601Z-debug.log
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

Comment: Can you explain which parts of that message are unclear?

Comment: i got the error above after i run 'ionic start myapp

Comment: Am new to ionic

Comment: Can you share parts of your configuration? There must be something referencing that package

Comment: @Woqhub can you please check your node, npm and ionic cli version ?

Comment: Thanks was able to solve the problem thanks guys

Comment: @Woqhub it would be great if you post here as an answer how did you solve it. I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Since OP didn't update with his solution, based on the original post I'm guessing he had an older version of NPM. This is a problem on Ubuntu because at least as of my posting this the standard one you get by running "apt install npm" is like version 5. To install NPM 10.x+, do this:

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install nodejs
```

I found this solution here (not affiliate or anything):

https://joshtronic.com/2018/05/08/how-to-install-nodejs-10-on-ubuntu-1804-lts/